# Xcode 6 Use the same View with 4 different viewcontrollers

Tags: ios, xcode

In my project I have a view that i would like to use with multiple ViewControllers.

For example : I have a View named WeekView and 7 ViewControllers. When the user opens the app, he'll see 7 buttons, each one takes him to a ViewController with the same View.

So my question is : Is it possible that I can use the same WeekView with all 7 ViewControllers, or should I create 7 Views?

Comment: You should definitely be using the same view.

Answer (score 0):

of course you can use 1 view (xib or storyboard) with many view controllers.

One import rule : never duplicate your source code ;-)

So if this view is the same 7 times, you don't need to duplicate it.

Comment: Even if the view have buttons that should be linked to a ViewController?

Comment: Create a ParentViewController with IBOutlet properties for each buttons and actions. Then inherit each other view controllers with your ParentViewController. With this solution each view controller have an access to buttons...

Comment: I dont have an idea on how to do it.. I've just started using objective-c